# Query over an array in mongoose returns empty array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I've a Menu model which has a list of members(roles) who can access it.When I try to query based on role, mongoose returns empty array. I created and populated Menu collection in mongoose terminal before creating the schema. When I execute the query in terminal it returns right records.Please help.

```
const MenuSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    menuId:{type:Number},
    menuName:{type:String},
    path:{type:String},
    accessTo:[{type:String}]
});

const Menu = module.exports = mongoose.model('Menu', MenuSchema);

module.exports.getMenuByRole = function(role, callback){

        console.log('rle'+role);
         const query = {"accessTo": role};
        Menu.find(query,callback);
    //   Menu.find(query, callback);

}
```

Here is the result of execution in terminal:

```
 db.Menu.find({"accessTo":"admin"})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d352f6c866e313fca373d1d"), "menuId" : 2, "menuName" : "Profile", "path" : "/profile", "accessTo" : [ "admin", "employees", "user" ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d352f73866e313fca373d1e"), "menuId" : 3, "menuName" : "Employees", "path" : "/employess", "accessTo" : [ "admin" ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .exec() with find.
And, accessTo is an array field you have to use $in, with it.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stackoverflow', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const MenuSchema = new Schema({
    menuId:{type:Number},
    menuName:{type:String},
    path:{type:String},
    accessTo:[{type:String}]
});

const menuModel = mongoose.model("Menu", MenuSchema)

function run(role){
    menuModel
    .find({ 
        accessTo: {
            $in: [role]
        } 
    })
    .exec((err, result) => {
        console.log("result", result)
    }, err => {
        console.log("err", err)
    }) 
}

run("admin")
```

Comment: It's returning the same result.it's [ ].

Comment: Have you inserted data in db? @sreeyachowdary. I have edited the code, did you use the changed copy?

Comment: Change the database url, I used in the example. To your own db's url. @sreeyachowdary

Comment: Actually I inserted records into "Menu" using mongo shell, But I was querying "Menus", which the code creates when we create the schema. So I deleted "Menu" which I created and ran the code. It created Menus and solved the problem.I'll mark your answer as right as it solved my other problem.

Comment: Thank you. An upvote too will be much appreciated. @sreeyachowdary